# React identity higher order component

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

How do I make an identity higher order component, i.e. a higher order component that just renders the input component?

To illustrate: Given the component

```
const TestComponent = () => <div>TEST</div>
```

I'd like the following to be equivalent:

```
export default TestComponent;
export default identityHOC(TestComponent);
```

I've tried

```
const identityHOC = (Component) => (props) => Component(props);
const identityHOC = (Component) => (props) => () => Component(props);
const identityHOC = (Component) => (props) => <Component {...props} />;
const identityHOC = (Component) => (props) => () => <Component {...props} />;
```

and other variations, but they don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HOC is basically **just a function**, which when supplied with a component, returns another (or same, if you want to) component.

**Try this**

```
import React from 'react';

const identityHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>;
    }
  }

  return HOC;
};
```

If you want to write it as a functional component,

```
import react from 'React'
const identityHOC = (WrappedComponent) => props => 
  (<WrappedComponent {...props}/>)
```

You might've forgotten to import React.

Answer (score 1):

To implement a HOC (extending from Vinay Chandran's Answer).

## To just render the component:

#### HOC

Define the HOC function. It should return something with the signature (props) => < Component>

```js
import react from 'React'
const wrapWithHOC = (WrappedComponent) => props => 
  (<WrappedComponent {...props}/>)
```

#### Base Component

```
const BaseComponent = () => (
    <div>TEST</div>
);

const WrappedComponent = wrapWithHOC(BaseComponent)
```

#### Used in App

```
<App>
    <WrappedComponent />
</App>
```

## With injected prop

#### HOC

```
import react from 'React'
const wrapWithHOC = (WrappedComponent) => props => 
  (<WrappedComponent externalProp="ExternalProp Example" {...props}/>)
```

#### Base Component

```
const BaseComponent = ({ internalProp, externalProp}) => (
    <div>
        internal prop is: {internalProp}
        external prop is: {externalProp || 'Not Wrapped'}
    </div>
);

const WrappedComponent = wrapWithHOC(BaseComponent)
```

#### Used in App

```
<App>
    <WrappedComponent internalProp="This is a standard prop" />
</App>
```